# Why are private variables accessible from outside a static nested class?

Tags: java, scope

I am having some trouble understanding the behavior of the `private` keyword in this instance:

```
public class OuterClass {
         static class StaticNestedClass {
              private int a = 4; 
              // Should not be accessible from outside the class
         }
         public static void main(String[] args) {
              StaticNestedClass c = new StaticNestedClass();
              System.out.println(c.a); 
              // This statement prints the value of a, even though b is private
         }
}
```

Instead of returning a compiler error, the main method is able to access the variable `a`, even though it is private. Why does it do this?

Also, is there any other way to make certain variables inside the nested class inaccessible to the main method?

**EDIT**
Note that this question is about *static nested classes*, not inner classes, and so the scope rules should be different.

Comment: Because you're doing everything in a single class. Private variables are always visible from the class that declares them, or any class containing this class.

Comment: Classes can see the private fields and methods of their inner classes. That's how it works. If you don't want `main` to see it, declare `main` in another class, or don't use an inner class.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to hide variables in the inner class from the main method, or is `private` just the wrong keyword to use?

Comment: @Aghast365: The purpose of `private` is primarily to protect things from being accessed by code that the programmer of the code using them would know nothing about.  If everything is all contained within the same source file, anyone with access to the code of the inner class would also be able to see anything done by code in the enclosing class.